# Resampling using gdalwarp gives me no data

Tags: gdal, geoprocessing, dem, geotiff-tiff, gdalwarp

I have an image with the following information.

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
    Files:test_DEM.tiff
    Size is 91, 73
    Coordinate System is:
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
    Origin = (-87.238000000000000,40.620599999999996)
    Pixel Size = (0.000100000000000,-0.000100000000000)
    Metadata:
      AREA_OR_POINT=Area
    Image Structure Metadata:
      INTERLEAVE=BAND
    Corner Coordinates:
    Upper Left  ( -87.2380000,  40.6206000) ( 87d14'16.80"W, 40d37'14.16"N)
    Lower Left  ( -87.2380000,  40.6133000) ( 87d14'16.80"W, 40d36'47.88"N)
    Upper Right ( -87.2289000,  40.6206000) ( 87d13'44.04"W, 40d37'14.16"N)
    Lower Right ( -87.2289000,  40.6133000) ( 87d13'44.04"W, 40d36'47.88"N)
    Center      ( -87.2334500,  40.6169500) ( 87d14' 0.42"W, 40d37' 1.02"N)
    Band 1 Block=91x22 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
      NoData Value=-3.40282001837565598e+38`enter code here`
```

I am trying to resample this image to a 5m x 5m resolution. I use the following command:

```
 gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -tr 5 5 -tap -r bilinear -dstnodata -3.40282e+38 test_DEM.tiff DEM_result.tiff
```

But no image is being created. I am not sure where I am going wrong. This is the message I am getting:

```
Creating output file that is 1P x 1L.
Processing input file 
test_DEM.tiff.
Using internal nodata values (eg. -3.40282e+38) for image test_DEM.tiff.
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
```

Comment: Target resolution is expressed in the same units as the projection, in this case EPSG:4326 and degrees. Your 5 by 5 degrees output pixel is much bigger than your whole image. I believe that your single pixel output is still correct, though useless.

Comment: Do I have to convert my target resolution (which is in meters) to degrees?. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Degrees do not convert nicely to meters because latitude and longitude have different scales except on the equator. You must read a bit about projections and select some projected coordinate system to warp to.

Comment: Could you direct me to a link that I could refer to. I am fairly new to this field